# How to handle error of "Could not find method android() on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I get the following error `ERROR: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_9fawur68cjcg5sfkvki95w8sr$_run_closure1@30cec325] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

I'm not sure why I get this error, and I've tried many other things to see if I can get it to work. Although it never does.

App level gradle has been modified many times none of which fix the issue. Project level gradle doesn't work right either.

**App level gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.troop59.LoginFirebase"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    //add this line
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
}
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

**Project level gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()

            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

                // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
                // in the individual module build.gradle files
            }
        }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the line

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

at the very beginning of your app-level `build.gradle` file.

[More info](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#module-level)

An [example on github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppShortcuts/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

You should also have this dependency in the project-level `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    ...
}
```

UPDATE #1

You must add the google repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and see if it helps.

Comment: ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
Open File
Is the error I get when I do that.

Comment: You add the line `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'` in the project dependencies.

Comment: I get this message

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Comment: ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Comment: ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

Comment: WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Also after I clicked 'do refactor'

I get two warnings as follows:

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Did you read http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html ? Because fixing those warnings is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

- As I can't add a comment ,so I will add Answer
- you should also
- Change every **Compile** to **Implementation**
- then Invalidates Cashes and restart (as follows)
- [[image: 1]]

Comment: Im currently getting this message with the      line
( see next post for message)

Comment: please update build.gradle(app) as I told then rebuilding your project

Comment: gradle is up to date. now I cant see the app run in the emulator.

Comment: Currently getting this :
02/14 08:40:50: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\resources\instant-run\debug\resources-debug.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk

Comment: C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk

Comment: C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk

Comment: C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk

Comment: C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk

Comment: C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk

Comment: C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk

Comment: C:\Users\juler\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\juler.DESKTOP-O1M7J01\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginFirebase\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
$ adb shell pm uninstall net.troop59.LoginFirebase
Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: net.troop59.LoginFirebase

Comment: at com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4289)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:21095)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:17916)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:736)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1486)
at

Comment: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:193)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
at

Comment: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
Error while Installing APKs